# how to host existing mysql+php web application on ibm bluemix

Tags: php, mysql, ibm-cloud, web-deployment, web-hosting

i'm new to web development. I've coded a sample application using MySQL and php in xampp. now the application is perfectly running on localhost.but i need to host that with free of cost.i tried GitHub pages.but i've got to know that GitHub don't support php+MySQL applications.even i want to try microsoft azure but it's saying you'r school email id is not registered.so i thought to try ibm bluemix. but i don't know how to host php,mysql applications on ibm bluemix.present i don't have anything except code on my computer.please,help me in this issue as soon as possible.i have only single day left to complete the task.

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use this as runtime - https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/starters/php - mind the pricing plan.
You then need to look for PHP Buildpacks (internet search) which include MySQL, and apply it via the CloudFoundry command line (check IBM Cloud documentation or this 
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/index.html).
Hope this helps for the next steps.

There is also a MySQL service, however, it doesn't come for free. However, I think the expected cost is low and I think you currently gain some free money to start with when registering for the first time.
https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mysql